# I can't ping6 my domains from outside. Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited

Tags: networking, dns, networkmanager, dhcp, ipv6

**Setup**

- Desktop computer (MyComputer)

  - Mobo: ASRock
  - Distro: Arch Linux
- Yunohost Server (Yunohost)

  - Mobo: Raspberry Pi 3
  - Distro: Debian
  - Main App: Yunohost/NextCloud
  - Domain registered at godaddy.com (mydomain.tld)
- Yunohost Server (Xroklaus)

  - Mobo: Raspberry Pi 3
  - Distro: Debian
  - Main App: Yunohost/Duniter
  - Domain registered at FreeDNS.afraid.org (guilder-test.eu.org)
- Modem

  - Fritz!Box 7581

My modem is automatically entering the wrong ipv6 address for at least two of my devices, resulting to DestinationNetworkUnreachable errors.

Tests from https://www.subnetonline.com

```
IPv6 Ping Output:

PING guilder-test.eu.org(2001:983:8610:1:2239:6fcb:6144:21d2 (2001:983:8610:1:2239:6fcb:6144:21d2)) 32 data bytes
From 2001:983:8610::1 (2001:983:8610::1) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
From 2001:983:8610::1 (2001:983:8610::1) icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
From 2001:983:8610::1 (2001:983:8610::1) icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited
From 2001:983:8610::1 (2001:983:8610::1) icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Administratively prohibited

--- guilder-test.eu.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3004ms
```

Modem settings
[image]
[image]

**Desktop computer**

[image]

My modem is automatically entering the wrong ipv6 address for my main computer.
The address it enters is `73a:34a1:5d16:a67f` when it should be `5766:a840:f358:5b00`.
I can manually edit it on the modem, but it will jump back to the old settings after some time.

IP lookup

```
[me@MyComputer ~]$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:983:8610:1:5766:a840:f358:5b00/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6571sec preferred_lft 3492sec
    inet6 fe80::90d9:53e6:a878:801c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Network settings
[image: Network settings]

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyWifi

```
[root@MyComputer ~]# cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyWifi
[connection]
id=MyWifi
uuid=109dd5bb-9f07-465f-b2ef-0f7e40084345
type=wifi
permissions=user:me:;

[wifi]
mac-address=30:10:B3:0A:1C:85
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=MyWifi

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=g4TK1DdyiPoOPo6tknNF4eInZthPEfyNYU7jJoRMXvuaea7pckpG43ahnBKZ5pJ

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

**Server computers**

The IPv6 interface ID that's picked up from one of the servers is correct, while the other enters either the link local scope or more surpisingly, the link local scope of the other server.

[image]

Thus the IPv6 interface ID of Yunohost resolves to either `::fb41:cbb3:2bec:e9c0` or the more suprising `::7664:c1e:6989:14b0` when it should be `::f3d5:e2a7:5d97:f45c`.

Interfaces on YunoHost

```
admin@YunoHost:~ $ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:983:8610:1:f3d5:e2a7:5d97:f45c/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 5916sec preferred_lft 3396sec
    inet6 fe80::fb41:cbb3:2bec:e9c0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 state DOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::3aa6:ea20:d318:e097/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Interfaces on Xroklaus

```
 admin@Xroklaus:~ $ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:983:8610:1:2239:6fcb:6144:21d2/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 5535sec preferred_lft 3461sec
    inet6 fe80::7664:c1e:6989:14b0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 state DOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::5f05:b808:f4ad:b037/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
admin@Yunohost:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

My other server has the same settings.

The modem also shows the two servers having a very odd connection, which does not reflect reality.

[image]

While Xroklaus looks normal

[image]

Yunohost on the other hand thinks it's connected to the modem via Xroklaus.

[image]

Comment: Is the modem working as a DHCPv6 server, or what do you mean by "my modem is entering the wrong ipv6 address"? There are two mechanisms by which hosts on a IPv6 LAN select their addresses: Stateless Address Autoconficuration (SLAAC) and DHCPv6. SLAAC works so that the router announces a prefix and hosts automatically select the lower part of the address, often based on the MAC address. DHCPv6 is more like DHCP(v4). A host can choose which mechanism it uses. SLAAC is the older of the two; maybe your hosts have chosen to use it instead of DHCPv6? `resolvconf.conf` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm not familiar with networking, so I thought I had to look over there. Should I use DHCPv6 only?

Comment: How do hosts automatically select the lower part of the address? I don't see MAC addresses being copied.

Comment: The MAC address is mapped to an EUI-64 64-bit identifier by flipping the "universal/local" bit and inserting `FFFE` in the middle. See https://howdoesinternetwork.com/2013/slaac-ipv6-stateless-address-autoconfiguration for the details.

Comment: The lower 64 bits of the address are typically randomly generated and non constant.  If you want IPv6 machines to be publicly addressable, you should give them a _fixed_ address, either by static configuration, or by using DHCP6 to assign a particular address to a given interface.  While older machines may use a fixed EUI-64 identifier permanently, many will change their IPv6 machine identifier (low 64 bits) every X hours.  Thus you may see addresses identified as "dynamic" or "dynamic deprecated" in your `ip -6 a` output.

Comment: As you could see in the question, they are 'dynamic noprefixroute'. They haven't changed ipv6 address as far as I can tell though. How do I give the machines fixed addresses? By choosing "Use static settings" on the modem? (image 1)

Comment: Correction, it looks like my desktop IS changing it's ipv6 address every few hours or so. My servers ipv6 addresses however remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Destination unreachable: **Administratively prohibited**" suggests there might be a firewall of some sort rejecting the IPv6 pings.

Comment: Yes. That firewall is apparently on the modem/router as I had been able to temporarily set the IPv6 interface IDs of all my computers on the modem to the correct interface hardware addresses. Thus I was able to ping6 my sites, until after a few minutes one by one, IPv6 Interface IDs were reset automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with a *Raspberry Pi 3B+* behind a Fritz!Box 7581, so my solution may work for you as well.

1. Edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` on the RPi and replace *slaac private* with *slaac hwaddr*.
2. Even though it appears that IPv6 is fully enabled on the RPi, it may actually in the latest version of Raspbian Stretch be blocked in `/etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf`. Removing this file, or commenting its contents, removes that blockage.
3. Make the `FB7581` forget about the "old" RPi by shutting it down, waiting until it is listed under the idle connections, and then removing it.
4. After (re)booting the RPi it should be possible under Permit Access to open it for Ping6, OpenVPN, etc. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on my FritzBox 6690 that I had to manually change the values of the IPv6 Interface-ID on Internet/Permit Access ("Internet/Freigaben" in german) to what is listed on my Raspberry (or any other device, that is). For some reason these fields contain the wrong values.

Comment: I actually did the opposite. 
`ip address add <ipv6 address> dev <interfacename>` did the trick for me. 
I figured that the router routes the ip packets correctly, but my server would not accept the packets because of the unregistered address.